# Writing SQL table using DBI library in R

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

I'm trying to use the dbWriteTable function in the DBI library to write an R dataframe into a SQL database. I used the following code to do so (where the second argument is the name of the table I'd like to create and the third is the name of the R dataframe):

```
dbWriteTable(con,"Dist2Shore_East_Coast",rawCoast)
```

But received this error:

> Error:  'CREATE TABLE "Dist2Shore_East_Coast" (   "x" FLOAT ) '
>   nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
>   Server][SQL Server]

Is there an issue with the arguments I used? Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you certain the user you use to connect with has permission to create tables?

Comment: Are you certain that the `Dist2Shore_East_Coast` table did not already exist before the above call to `dbWriteTable`?

Comment: I think the error is cut off. Are you providing the full message? Also, what library are you using? Only DBI? RSQLServer? RODBC? odbc?